Swapping contents of two drives with the same capacity
I have two flash drives, for example, and due to USB speeds prefer have the contents of one on the other and vice versa. This includes the MBR and EFI bootloaders. I am not referring to swap space. How can this be achieved without requiring a lot of RAM for buffering and error corrrction for example?
Thanks for reaching out.

What size (GB) are these flash drives, and is there any reason why the obvious "take a disk image of (a), copy (b) to (a), copy disk image back to (b)" solution can't be used?

@ChrisDavies, 32GB. There s no ram issues, about 12GB total

(1) Is there a third device where you can temporarily store 32GB as a regular file? (2) Are you sure the two drives in question are exactly of the same size? How did you check? A good way is e.g. blockdev --getsize64 /dev/….

@ChrisDavis There is only little space left anywhere to store the images on the harddisk or anything. I think only splitting in 8 parts and storing each in RAM is probably a somewhat decent solution.

Let me ask you this. How valuable is the data on these two USB sticks? How upset would you be if the data was lost? If the answer is that it's important to any degree whatsoever then buy or borrow some storage to allow you to copy data from each device in one hit. Otherwise, (a) a crash will lose all the data in both sticks, (b) a single read or write error could lose all the data on both sticks, (c) any program error could lose all the data... you get the picture?

@ChrisDavies, sure, they're not valuable at all

Here you go. I'm somewhat hesitant to post this at all, but on testing with images files it worked correctly. There is very little (no!) error checking so use it at your own risk.
I repeat my warning from the comments:
How valuable is the data on these two USB sticks? How upset would you be if the data was lost? If the answer is that it's important to any degree whatsoever then buy or borrow some storage to allow you to copy data from each device in one hit. Otherwise:

a crash will lose all the data in both sticks
a single read or write error could lose all the data on both sticks
any program error could lose all the data on both sticks

Do you get the picture?
Do not just blindly run this. Make sure you understand what's going on. Do not run this on USB sticks with mounted filesystems.
#!/bin/sh
#
# swap.sh: a script to swap data between two same-sized devices
#
usb1=img1                       # Path to raw USB stick #1 (/dev/...)
usb2=img2                       # Path to raw USB stick #2 (/dev/...)

size=$((200*1024*1024))         # Transfer chunk size (200MB here)
swap=/dev/shm/chunk             # Somewhere on tmpfs that can hold a $size byte file

usb1size="$(blockdev --getsize64 "$usb1" 2>/dev/null || stat -c %s "$usb1")"
usb2size="$(blockdev --getsize64 "$usb2" 2>/dev/null || stat -c %s "$usb2")"
if [ "${usb1size:-0}" -ne "${usb2size:-0}" ] || [ "${usb1size:-0}" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Devices are not the same size: ${usb1size:-<unknown>} - ${usb2size:-<unknown>}" >&2
    exit 1
fi

chunknr=0                       # Current chunk number
offset=0                        # Chunk offset (bytes)

while [ "$offset" -lt "$usb1size" ]
do
    echo "Chunk of size $size for chunk $chunknr (offset $offset)" >&2

    # Copy from $usb1 to memory
    dd bs="$size" count=1 skip="$chunknr" iflag=fullblock if="$usb1" of="$swap"

    # Copy from $usb2 to $usb1
    # dd bs="$size" count=1 skip="$chunknr" seek="$chunknr" conv=notrunc iflag=fullblock if="$usb2" of="$usb1"

    # Copy from memory to $usb2
    # dd bs="$size" count=1 seek="$chunknr" conv=notrunc iflag=fullblock if="$swap" of="$usb2"

    # Next chunk
    chunknr=$((chunknr+1))
    offset=$((chunknr * size))
done

rm -f "$swap"

You can test this by creating a couple of test files. For example, here are two 1GB test files:
yes yesterday | dd bs=$((1024*1024)) count=1024 iflag=fullblock >img1
yes tomorrow | dd bs=$((1024*1024)) count=1024 iflag=fullblock >img2

md5sum img1 img2        # Get a checksum for each of the two image files
./swap.sh               # Run the code
md5sum img1 img2        # Verify visually that the checksums have swapped

Uncomment the two destructive dd commands when you are sure that it is going to work as you expect.

OP doesn't explicitly say the drives are exactly the same size, and might not be game, anyway, but the classic old-school algorithm, given two objects of exactly the same size (in bytes), was:  A = A XOR B; B = A XOR B;  A = A XOR B.  Step 1 puts the "difference mask" in A, where A now holds 1 bits everywhere the two differ, and 0 bits everywhere they're the same. Step 2 applies that mask to B.  So now B contains the old A.  Step 3 applies the mask to B, storing the result in A. So now A contains B.  QED!  Pity it requires a total of 6 reads and 3 writes through the entire drives! :)

1/2 @JimL. agreed that the devices might not be the same size. I might update the code to refuse to play if the sizes aren't the same, but at the end of the day I posted it with considerable hesitation

2/2 @JimL. XOR is fine at the byte/word level, but at the shell script level it's better to swap out A=X, X=Y, Y=A for reasonably large blocks. Remember an XOR operation requires an implicit read before the XOR can be reapplied, as there's no native block XOR operation accessible to the shell

It should be faster to read two chunks (/dev/shm/chunk_usb1 /dev/shm/chunk_usb2) in parallel then likewise write two chunks. Otherwise, unless additional kernel caches help to make it more parallel, each drive is twiddling thumbs while the other is reading/writing.

conv=sparse could be a source of data corruption since dd can not distinguish between intentional/significant zeroes and free space. Given the large block size it should be unlikely to happen, but if you were to write a large file full of zeroes, you might end up with previous data after swapping.

@frostschutz for what's probably a one-off for most people I'm not sure the optimisation would be worthwhile. Also, if they're on the same USB bus will it really make much difference?

@frostschutz, "you might end up with previous data after swapping" - oops, thank you. It was a false optimisation that I've removed

@ChrisDavies Agreed.  I didn't mean to imply that my idea was practical! :) It's just a data-swap algorithm that requires no temporary storage.
